# change password generator policy

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin. I really want to know if there is a way to change the password generator strength for the generate button (because on my Mysql Server it has a symbol, but the password generator on phpmyadmin can't generate any). Is there a way which I can modify phpmyadmin file to generate a password containing symbols?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could edit the list of available characters in [js/functions.js](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/js/functions.js#L452):

```
var pwchars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ';
```

You should probably use care to only allow characters that make sense to MySQL in this context.